# Node.js: Which module to "require('..')" to use socket.io？

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, require

In https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/test/socket.io.js

The code:

[image]

**What is the module name to require?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires the module from the parent directory - in this case, socket.io

Answer (score 2):

A folder can be used as a module if that folder contains, `index.js` or `package.json` files etc.

So in this case it is requiring the `socket.io.js` file in the above folder.

Also if a `package.json` and `index.js` file are in the same folder the `package.json` will get look up priority.